# How does this parsing function using stringstream work?

Tags: c++, parsing, vector, stringstream

so I made a function to parse a given string with a comma delimiter last semester during a haze. Its very likely I took much of it from guides online, but it worked for the overall project so I did it. Now i'm going back and reviewing it, and i'm confused. Here is the code

`vector parsedString(string line){
vector splitStrings;

```
stringstream inputString(line);

    while(inputString.good()){
        string substr;
        getline(inputString,substr,',');
        splitStrings.push_back(substr);
                
        substr = "";
        }

return splitStrings;
```

}`

The purpose was to put each part of the line thats seperated into a vector, then take that vector back where its needed with all the parts. However, I do NOT understand the stringstream aspects of this.

To be specific, when I wrote code to check stringstreams contents during the loop, it stayed the same for the entire time. If `getline()` is supposed to track where the last delimiter was, why does it not show in the contents?

also if possible, an explanation on how `.good()` works in this case would be phenomenal. I understand stringstream is a stream, and function of that sort are supposed to check if streams are finished or not, but again I don't understand how the program would know that.

Everything works as intended, there is no mistakes being made from what I can see. I just fundamentally can't seem to grasp why its working, and I don't want my lack of knowledge to come back to bite me.

Comment: `If getline() is supposed to track where the last delimiter was, why does it not show in the contents?` it doesn't, your stream tracks it. Why do you think the content of stringstream should change though? It probably just remembers the offset. Also: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/good

Comment: This code is flawed. If `getline(inputString,substr,',');` fails you'll use that data before checking the stream state again. A better loop is `while (getline(inputString,substr,',')) { splitStrings.push_back(substr); }`

Comment: Same concept as [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons) which is check for the condition you care about, not the one you don't.

Answer (score 0):

A `istringstream` is not just a `string`. If it were, it would be redundant.

For a first approximation, you could think of it as a class whose instances contain a `string` *and* a position (i.e., a string index). When you construct the `istringstream` from a `string`, the position is initialised to 0. When you read a character from the `istringstream`, you get the character at the position, and the position is incremented. So each time you read a character, you get the next one. (Actually, a `stringstream` has two positions, one for reading and one for writing, because it's a combination of an `istringstream` and an `ostreamstring`. But only the input part is relevant to your question.)

All other stream input operations are based on reading a single character, although implementations are allowed to be more efficient if the results are the same.

The above was an oversimplification, of course. A stream has other state: status bits, formatting parameters, locale settings, and more stuff I'm forgetting. See [this overview for more details](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream). But the basic point stands: the string is only a part of a `stringstream`'s state: the rest of the state is used to make it look like an I/O stream. Which turns out to be useful if you want to pick it apart sequentially into tokens.